# What does the compiler with the code and why the nested struct throwing error?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct node{
int val;
node *next;
} node;
node *start;
```

Here this code throws an error on line 3. But if I modify it like this,

```
typedef struct node{
int val;
struct node *next;
} node;
node *start;
```

This is correct?
But why the compiler do so? And how the compiler execute it?

Comment: Just a quick tip! As you declared `node *start`... While declaring a pointer variable, if it is not assigned to anything then it contains a garbage value. Therefore, it is recommended to assign a NULL value to it. e.g. `node* start = NULL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `node` type doesn't exist until after the end of the `typedef` declaration, so it cannot be referenced in the structure body.  But the structure tag in `struct node` can.

My preferred solution is to declare the `typedef` using a forward reference to the structure definition, then define the structure in a second declaration.  The advantage is that it allows the `typedef` name to be used inside the structure defintion.  It looks like this:

```
typedef struct node node;
struct node {
    int val;
    node *next;
};
```

This allows you to use the `typedef` name `node` consistently in all declarations, including the ones inside the structure definition.